# Printing Iframe content

Tags: javascript, printing, cross-browser

Can any one tell me the complete cross browser solution to print the contents of iframe.I followed the following links.But it is not working in chrome 3.0 browser & IE8.It is printing the entire page.

[How do I print an IFrame from javascript in Safari/Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472951/how-do-i-print-an-iframe-from-javascript-in-safari-chrome)

[Print iframe content in Opera and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648594/print-iframe-content-in-opera-and-chrome)

Thanks for your valuable help...

Comment: I too am struggling with this.  While those links claim to be cross-browser, I get the entire page printed in most, if not all, IEs.

Comment: @jolo Till now I am not succeeded with that. Finally I ended up opening a new window to print. Please keep me posted if you get a solution somewhere. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As to Chrome, version 3 is way ancient. Please give a try to some newer version (like Chrome 16) and see if it works there.