# how can I print iframe content

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want to print iframe content and I could not do it, I found [the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648594/print-iframe-content-in-opera-and-chrome) I'm a new promgrammer so i didn't understant the question and answers please explane me a few simple
thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

**Here it is :**

Your iframe :

```
<iframe id="printf" name="printf"></iframe>
```

Printing :

```
window.frames["printf"].focus();
window.frames["printf"].contentWindow.print();
```

BTW, try to explain your problem in a better way next time (posting code can help) =)

*Ref* : [Javascript Print iframe contents only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616426/javascript-print-iframe-contents-only)

**EDIT :**

As OP said didn't work, i'm referring the testpage which was linked in Ref:

[Print an iframe](http://plungjan.name/SO/testprintiframe.html)

You can also try this function (same ref, different poster) :

```
//id is the  id of the iframe
function printFrame(id) {
            var frm = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow;
            frm.focus();// focus on contentWindow is needed on some ie versions
            frm.print();
            return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm all ready tried  but it didn't work.I need another solution

Comment: Your solution works in Chrome but not in (at least) IE11, didnt try other browsers. In IE11, It's printing the outerwindow and the iframe