# Dynamic Iframe printing

Tags: javascript

I want to dynamically set the content of an iframe to that of an html document I have.  It is in the form of a string in memory in javascript.

Then i want to print that iframe.

Ideas?

Comment: Here's the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472951/how-do-i-print-an-iframe-from-javascript-in-safari-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

```
var iframe = document.getElementByID("some ID");
iframe.contentDocument.write("HTML string");
iframe.contentWindow.print();
```