# printing a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I just print the article on my web page using jQuery, article is inside a div
***window.print()*** will print the entire window.
So little confused with that...!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use jQuery ... use css and media=print.  Here is an [article for reference](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/), and [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200001.html).

Basically, create a new stylesheet for what you want to show when you print, and set the media to print:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably put the content in an iframe and call print() on that window.

A quick google gave me http://www.eggheadcafe.com/PrintSearchContent.asp?LINKID=449 which mentions you must `focus()` before you `print()`. Note that that page is a few years old.

Also see [How do I print an IFrame from javascript in Safari/Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472951/how-do-i-print-an-iframe-from-javascript-in-safari-chrome).

Answer (score 1):

Styling html for printing is commonly achieved using a different style sheet, e.g. in your head element:

```
<head>
    ...

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
    ...

</head>
```

The style sheet style.css is used to style your html on screen, while print.css is used to style your html for print. By providing the appropriate styling in print.css you can easily show or hide html elements to achieve the output you are looking for.