# Can I send a pdf file to the printer automatically?

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
<iframe src="ACRBusinessCL.pdf" id="PDFtoPrint" height="800" width="800">
</iframe>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="document.getElementById('PDFtoPrint').focus(); document.getElementById('PDFtoPrint').contentWindow.print();">
</form>
```

What's driving me crazy is: I thought I had this working at one point.
The pdf file is showing up in the iframe, but when I click Print, nothing happens.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472951/how-do-i-print-an-iframe-from-javascript-in-safari-chrome>

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printPage(yoururl) {
            var w = window.open(yoururl);
            w.document.write(yoururl);
            w.print();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: This answer is very poor. Add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: url is getting printed