# Print external HTML file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I have a "print" button on `index.html`. What code do I need to print the `print.html` file? I mean, when I press the button from `index.html`, print the page `print.html`.

Comment: No load. I need to print external file by button.

Answer (score 3):

```js
function closePrint () {
  document.body.removeChild(this.__container__);
}

function setPrint () {
  this.contentWindow.__container__ = this;
  this.contentWindow.onbeforeunload = closePrint;
  this.contentWindow.onafterprint = closePrint;
  this.contentWindow.focus(); // Required for IE
  this.contentWindow.print();
}

function printPage (sURL) {
  var oHiddFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
  oHiddFrame.onload = setPrint;
  oHiddFrame.style.visibility = "hidden";
  oHiddFrame.style.position = "fixed";
  oHiddFrame.style.right = "0";
  oHiddFrame.style.bottom = "0";
  oHiddFrame.src = sURL;
  document.body.appendChild(oHiddFrame);
}
```

Then use

```html
onclick="printPage('print_url');"
```

Comment: great solution -- deserves more appreciation imo

Comment: Awesome solution!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `window.print()`

---

**Update**

Just noticed you've specified file names in there and that you want to print `print.html` when a button on `index.html` is clicked. There's no built-in way to do this (in the sense that you can't pass any arguments to `window.print()` indicating the document to print). What you could do is load the document to print into an iframe or open a new window and on load, invoke `window.print()` on that container.

Here are some forum posts and web pages that talk about the same thing:

- http://www.highdots.com/forums/javascript/printing-another-web-file-present-274201.html
- http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3524974.htm
- http://www.felgall.com/jstip29.htm

---

**Update 2**

Here's some quick-and-dirty code - note that this will only work if both your pages are in the same domain. Additionally, Firefox seems to fire the `load` event for an empty iframe also - so the print dialog will be displayed immediately on load, even when no `src` value was set for the iframe.

**index.html**

```
<html> 
<head> 
  <title>Index</title> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#loaderFrame').load(function(){
            var w = (this.contentWindow || this.contentDocument.defaultView);
            w.print();
        });

        $('#printerButton').click(function(){
            $('#loaderFrame').attr('src', 'print.html');
        });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
     #loaderFrame{
        visibility: hidden;
        height: 1px;
        width: 1px;
     }
  </style>
</head> 
<body> 
    <input type="button" id="printerButton" name="print" value="Print It" />

    <iframe id="loaderFrame" ></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**print.html**

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>To Print</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    Lorem Ipsum - this is print.html
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Update 3**
You might also want to see this: [How do I print an IFrame from javascript in Safari/Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472951/how-do-i-print-an-iframe-from-javascript-in-safari-chrome)

Comment: Can you give code, because I'm new and... But I don't want the page to be visible... Just when I press the button on index.html the page print.html be printed...

Comment: I don't think all browsers would allow that - it could be a security issue. I'm updating the answer, please check in a couple of minutes.

Comment: As for making the content to be printed invisible, you could style the new window or the iFrame with CSS so that it's either hidden or of a very small size - note that a browser may have some restrictions about making windows smaller than a certain size. I'd suggest using an iFrame instead.

Comment: @vladchooo I've updated my answer to add two simple HTML pages to demonstrate. I've used jQuery because it makes things a lot simpler. This works in FF4.0.1, Chrome 11 and IE 8. However, Firefox does have a problem that it will fire the load event even for an iframe with no `src` set. You'll need to work around that. Let me know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JQuery printPage plugin (https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-printPage-plugin). This plugin works fine and you can simply print an external html page.

Example:

```
 <html> 
    <head> 
      <title>Index</title> 
      <script src="http://www.position-absolute.com/creation/print/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="http://www.position-absolute.com/creation/print/jquery.printPage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
             $(".btnPrint").printPage();
         });
      </script>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <input type="button" id="printerButton" name="print" value="Print It" />

        <p><a class="btnPrint" href='iframe.html'>Print!</a></p>
    </body>
 </html>
```