# Save Page / Print Page buttons for the page that iframe src is linking to

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming I have outerpage.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="printPage" name="printPage" />
    <input type="button" id="savePage" name="savePage" />
    <iframe src="someOtherPage.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I use Javascript to save and print someOtherPage.html when the respective buttons are clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Use the window.print() method.

Also refer to the following link for similar question and answer.

[How do I print an IFrame from javascript in Safari/Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472951/how-do-i-print-an-iframe-from-javascript-in-safari-chrome)