# How to print pdf in iframe using javascript in ie6?

Tags: javascript

I have displayed a pdf in iframe which is in aspx page. I am working on IE6 browser. I use the following html and javascript code.

```
<iframe id = "frame_singleCheque" src = "../pdf/SingleCheque.pdf" runat = "server" style ="height:400px; width: 750px; overflow:scroll;" />


function printDoc()
{
      window.frames['ctl00_contPlcHdrMasterHolder_frame_singleCheque'].focus();
      window.frames['ctl00_contPlcHdrMasterHolder_frame_singleCheque'].print();
}

<input type="button" id = "btnCPrint" value = "Print" onclick="javascript:printDoc()" />
```

If press print button it shows print dialog. but whenever I press print button it doesn't print any thing. It doesn't print event a blank page. How can I print it?

Comment: [http://www.ie6countdown.com/](http://www.ie6countdown.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function printDoc() {
   document.getElementById('frame_singleCheque').focus(); 
   document.getElementById('frame_singleCheque').contentWindow.print();
}
```

**EDIT**: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472951/how-do-i-print-an-iframe-from-javascript-in-safari-chrome) as well.

Comment: Dear Behrang Saeedzadeh, I have already used this. But it prints whole page except iframe portion.

Comment: @Mahedee: Are you sure you include `contentWindow` as well? In your code you have not specified the `contentWindow`.