# Print an iFrame using document.frames in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, iframe, printing

This is driving me crazy.

I've been through several questions on here and other websites and cannot get this to work.

I have an iFrame within my parent page, containing a PDF document.

The iFrame (and PDF) is small, so the Adobe Reader navigation is hidden making it impractical to use the Print function within Adobe Reader.

So, I want a button (which has to be in the Parent frame) which can trigger `Print` on the iFrame window.

[print a PDF Iframe in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165821/print-a-pdf-iframe-in-firefox)

[How to print pdf in iframe using javascript in ie6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130299/how-to-print-pdf-in-iframe-using-javascript-in-ie6)

and a few other have similar suggestions.

Using **Firefox**

```
document.getElementById('loyaltyBadge').focus();
document.getElementById('loyaltyBadge').contentWindow.print();
```

Does nothing

```
document.frames['loyaltyBadge'].focus();
document.frames['loyaltyBadge'].contentWindow.print();
```

Does nothing

```
document.frames.loyaltyBadge.focus();
document.frames.loyaltyBadge.contentWindow.print();
```

Returns `document.frames is undefined`... as does:

```
document.loyaltyBadge.print();
```

Although this works in `Chrome`

I don't want to auto-print on load, but I need a print button.

All the lines above are being wrapped in:

```
$('#printFrame').click(function () {  });
```

The button having an id of `printFrame` and the frame itself has an ID (and name) of `loyaltyBadge`

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me in Firefox 11:

```
window.frames.loyaltyBadge.focus();
window.frames.loyaltyBadge.print();
```

Comment: Really?! That's strange, it just won't do anything for me. I'm on FF 12, but I don't see why that should have stopped it!!

Comment: I have checked the click event is being captured OK, by adding an alert in there too, that works but then nothing else happens.

Comment: argh! It does work in isolation! There's obviously something else screwing up my code... I'll start tearing it apart!

Comment: OK, after a bit of fiddling I have worked something out, but not solved the issue. New question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683066/printing-contents-of-an-iframe-which-has-redirected-to-a-pdf-with-javascript-fir

Comment: Any version of Firefox since pdf.js was integrated this has stopped working. Best bug I can find on it: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=647658

Comment: In FF17 does not work, displays the following message "Error: Permission denied access to property 'print'"