# How to disable print preview on Google Chrome ver 38?

Tags: google-chrome, print-preview

I have develop POS using web browser.  But when I use onload="window.print();" a print preview appears and you need to press the ok to proceed printing.

There are recommendations from other sources to add --disable-print-preview on the short-cut. These appears to be working on old versions.

What version this extension works? or any other way to disable from the latest version of chrome?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Hi John, did you ever get this fixed using the `--kiosk-printing` argument?

Answer (score 4):

The command-line argument `--disable-print-preview` works on the newest version of Chrome, I've just tested it myself.

I'm using Chrome 44.0.2403.107 (64-bit).

If you want not only to skip the print preview but the system print dialog too, use the `--kiosk-printing` command line option instead.

Make sure Chrome gets shut down completely before you relaunch it, as it likes to hang out as a background process. You might need to restart your computer to get it to work.

Comment: I am using Chrome 38, Windows 7 "(32 Bit)

Comment: The chrome print preview is now hidden. The print preview for windows appears. It does not directly print to printer.

Comment: @JohnArzaga Sorry, didn't know that you needed to skip the system dialog too. For that, use chrome's `--kiosk-printing` command line option.

Comment: This "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-print-preview --kiosk-printing doesn work for me

Answer (score 0):

This has been annoying me for years this works

Hit Windows key + R to bring up the Run dialog and enter the following:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe  --disable-print-preview

This removes the print preview which is great but on when shutting down the computer and restarting you will have to run it again.

As a fix for this set up a scheduled task see link below

http://www.howtogeek.com/138159/how-to-enable-programs-and-custom-scripts-to-run-at-boot/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

1. Task manager -> Chrome -> end process
2. Chrome Properties Target: ( "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk-printing) apply and ok
3. Start Chrome ,Finish

[image: It's working for me]