# Print Receipt Directly With Angular

Tags: angular

I have created a sample project using angular version 7 my requirement whenever the users press on enter button report will print directly without preview.
I'm trying to find the library for print directly without preview in angular but not found  i think it should be have library that it can do that so i hope the members in stackoverflow can help me

Comment: Could you show what you have tried, and explain why it's not working as expected?

Comment: I'm trying to find the library for print directly without preview in angular but not found i think it should be have library that it can do that i hope the members in stackoverflow can help me

Comment: Do you want to print to the browser's terminal? If so it's `console.log`, do you want to "print" inside of the DOM (the HTML elements)? If so, `{{ my_variable }}`. If none of these are what you are looking for, I recommend you explain what you mean by "print without preview". Showing the code where you want to insert the "print" would help too.

Comment: This could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656372/select-a-printer-and-silently-print

Answer (score 0):

I believe the process printing is related to the browser,not to the web application.I think we can set chrome to run in kiosk mode so it won't give you a preview while printing. similar options are available in Mozilla Firefox.
for chrome: [How to disable print preview on Google Chrome ver 38?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643913/how-to-disable-print-preview-on-google-chrome-ver-38)

There is no way to disable print preview using javascript. refer [Disable print preview in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331771/disable-print-preview-in-chrome/30331858#30331858)

Comment: you have to close all instance of chrome and start with those parameters.then it will work