# Firefox is not responding to the click. No error in Firebug and nothing is happening. Chrome it is working fine

Tags: asp.net, pdf, iframe

This is the code i used to print the pdf inside and iframe.
But in Firefox its not even responding. No error in firebug.
In chrome its working fine.
Please help me.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function Printpd(pdf)
        {
                pdf.focus();
                pdf.print();
        }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
            <iframe name="myFrame" id="myFrame" width="600" height="400" src="uploadedfiles/DPA%20Quick%20Reference%20Guide.pdf""></iframe>

            <input type="button" value="Print IFRAME" onclick="Printpd(myFrame);" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe Firefox needs contentWindow

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472951/how-do-i-print-an-iframe-from-javascript-in-safari-chrome

Comment: I tried that one..But didn't worked..

Answer (score 0):

This will resolve the IFrame reference, it won't solve your printing issue, see link from @Nikki9696 for that:

```
<input type="button" value="Print IFRAME" 
        onclick="Printpd(document.getElementById('myFrame'));" />
```

Comment: can you give me a link for @Nikki9696. i dont know where to see.