# print another page from the current page without popup / showing contents of target page

Tags: jquery, html, printing, printing-web-page

I want to print another page from the current page, without popup the target page using jquery plugin or any other easy way?

Means current page has a button to print. When I press print, second page print to printer without popup or showing contents of target page.

Comment: Not really. You can have a stylesheet with `media="print"` to make the current page look different when printed.

Answer (score 1):

1. include the 2nd page in an iframe (hide it with style="display:none")
2. add a print function in the header of the other page which you can call from the main page with javascript, as in this answer: [How do I print an IFrame from javascript in Safari/Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472951/how-do-i-print-an-iframe-from-javascript-in-safari-chrome#answer-473270)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to modify the display of the page (use display:none for example to hide elements) :

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="print" />`