# how to print iframe google docs viewer open document

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I am using google docs viewer for show my uploaded document and i want to print it, but i can't print those document using jQuery.

I want to print iframe document but it is not by my code. how to print that document??

```
<button id="printbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Print</button>

<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=<?php echo urlencode(UPLOAD_URL.$file_name); ?>&embedded=true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframe" style="border: none;" width="800" height="470"></iframe>

<script>
function myFunction(){
    window.frames["iframe"].focus();
    window.frames["iframe"].print();    // NOT WORKING
}
</script>
```

Please help me......

Comment: I'm not sure but it's the same problem :[Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486363/how-do-print-specific-content-inside-the-iframe)

Comment: In this problem show html of other website bu in my problem i have open word or pdf file.

Comment: Are you using wordpress or else?

Answer (score 1):

I did some digging, found its not possible, 
because docs.google is going to be a different domain from yours. 
I tried this,

```
document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.print()
```

and got 'Blocked a frame with origin "http://mydomain" from accessing a cross-origin frame.'.

---

Lets say, even if google allowed cross domain, the print function wont work. because google docs viewer opens another window for printing.

I've reached a conclusion that google devs have smartly made this not possible.

Comment: I wasn't aware triggering a print command is as easy as that though. It's impressive.

Comment: It won't work if you are printing an iframe element from another domain due to Cross Origin Policy.