# javascript print() method is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, w3c

I have a simple HTML code to print the page. Below is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
function printPage()
{
    var w = window.open("http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/CofADocRequest.do?symbol=209104&LotNo=MKBP0842V&brandTest=SIGMA","_self");
    window.focus();
   window.print();
   }
</script>

</head>
<body >
<input type="button" onclick="printPage()" value="print a div!" />
</body>
</html>
```

What the code does is, it displays a button, on clicking that button it calls a function. The function uses open() to open a new URL in the same page by using the “_self ” parameter.

As we can see in the code, the print() is being called after the call to open method. But in my browser IE11, the print pop is being shown befor loading the page.
Due to this I am not printing the correct page.

Can anybody help me on this.

Comment: Checkout this question [print iframe][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088967/javascript-print-method-is-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `window` refers to the current window, which is the original.
By opening a new window in self you replace the page, this is basically a redirect.
And if you open it via popup and print it as `w.print()` than you run into cross-origin security error.

You could use iframe to this with a proxy as shown here 
[How do print specific content inside the iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486363/how-do-print-specific-content-inside-the-iframe)
and 
here
[How do print specific content inside the iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486363/how-do-print-specific-content-inside-the-iframe)