# site freezes after closing the print window

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I am using `jquery.printElement.js` to `print`. When I click on `print` button a `print window` opens with `print` and `cancel` button.  If I print the document or cancel the print window every thing works fine, but if I close the window with the `close` button in the `title bar` `[x]` than everything stops working after dispose of print window on `chrome` version `35`.

```
/// <reference path="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" />
/*
* Print Element Plugin 1.2
*
* Copyright (c) 2010 Erik Zaadi
*
* Inspired by PrintArea (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/PrintArea) and
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472951/how-do-i-print-an-iframe-from-javascript-in-safari-chrome
*
*  Home Page : http://projects.erikzaadi/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement 
*  Issues (bug reporting) : http://github.com/erikzaadi/jQueryPlugins/issues/labels/printElement
*  jQuery plugin page : http://plugins.jquery.com/project/printElement 
*  
*  Thanks to David B (http://github.com/ungenio) and icgJohn (http://www.blogger.com/profile/11881116857076484100)
*  For their great contributions!
* 
* Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
*   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
*   
*   Note, Iframe Printing is not supported in Opera and Chrome 3.0, a popup window will be shown instead
*/
; (function (window, undefined) {
    var document = window["document"];
    var $ = window["jQuery"];
    $.fn["printElement"] = function (options) {
        var mainOptions = $.extend({}, $.fn["printElement"]["defaults"], options);
        //iframe mode is not supported for opera and chrome 3.0 (it prints the entire page).
        //http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=2cb0f08dce8821c3&hl=en
        if (mainOptions["printMode"] == 'iframe') {
            if ($.browser.opera || (/chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())))
                mainOptions["printMode"] = 'popup';
        }
        //Remove previously printed iframe if exists
        $("[id^='printElement_']").remove();

        return this.each(function () {
            //Support Metadata Plug-in if available
            var opts = $.meta ? $.extend({}, mainOptions, $(this).data()) : mainOptions;
            _printElement($(this), opts);
        });
    };
    $.fn["printElement"]["defaults"] = {
        "printMode": 'iframe', //Usage : iframe / popup
        "pageTitle": '', //Print Page Title
        "overrideElementCSS": null,
        /* Can be one of the following 3 options:
        * 1 : boolean (pass true for stripping all css linked)
        * 2 : array of $.fn.printElement.cssElement (s)
        * 3 : array of strings with paths to alternate css files (optimized for print)
        */
        "printBodyOptions": {
            "styleToAdd": 'padding:10px;margin:10px;', //style attributes to add to the body of print document
            "classNameToAdd": '' //css class to add to the body of print document
        },
        "leaveOpen": false, // in case of popup, leave the print page open or not
        "iframeElementOptions": {
            "styleToAdd": 'border:none;position:absolute;width:0px;height:0px;bottom:0px;left:0px;', //style attributes to add to the iframe element
            "classNameToAdd": '' //css class to add to the iframe element
        }
    };
    $.fn["printElement"]["cssElement"] = {
        "href": '',
        "media": ''
    };
    function _printElement(element, opts) {
        //Create markup to be printed
        var html = _getMarkup(element, opts);

        var popupOrIframe = null;
        var documentToWriteTo = null;
        if (opts["printMode"].toLowerCase() == 'popup') {
            popupOrIframe = window.open('about:blank', 'printElementWindow', 'width=650,height=440,scrollbars=yes');
            documentToWriteTo = popupOrIframe.document;
        }
        else {
            //The random ID is to overcome a safari bug http://www.cjboco.com.sharedcopy.com/post.cfm/442dc92cd1c0ca10a5c35210b8166882.html
            var printElementID = "printElement_" + (Math.round(Math.random() * 99999)).toString();
            //Native creation of the element is faster..
            var iframe = document.createElement('IFRAME');
            $(iframe).attr({
                style: opts["iframeElementOptions"]["styleToAdd"],
                id: printElementID,
                className: opts["iframeElementOptions"]["classNameToAdd"],
                frameBorder: 0,
                scrolling: 'no',
                src: 'about:blank'
            });
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
            documentToWriteTo = (iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument);
            if (documentToWriteTo.document)
                documentToWriteTo = documentToWriteTo.document;
            iframe = document.frames ? document.frames[printElementID] : document.getElementById(printElementID);
            popupOrIframe = iframe.contentWindow || iframe;
        }
        focus();
        documentToWriteTo.open();
        documentToWriteTo.write(html);
        documentToWriteTo.close();
        _callPrint(popupOrIframe);
    };

    function _callPrint(element) {
        if (element && element["printPage"])
            element["printPage"]();
        else
            setTimeout(function () {
                _callPrint(element);
            }, 50);
    }

    function _getElementHTMLIncludingFormElements(element) {
        var $element = $(element);
        //Radiobuttons and checkboxes
        $(":checked", $element).each(function () {
            this.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
        });
        //simple text inputs
        $("input[type='text']", $element).each(function () {
            this.setAttribute('value', $(this).val());
        });
        $("select", $element).each(function () {
            var $select = $(this);
            $("option", $select).each(function () {
                if ($select.val() == $(this).val())
                    this.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
            });
        });
        $("textarea", $element).each(function () {
            //Thanks http://blog.ekini.net/2009/02/24/jquery-getting-the-latest-textvalue-inside-a-textarea/
            var value = $(this).attr('value');
            //fix for issue 7 (http://plugins.jquery.com/node/13503 and http://github.com/erikzaadi/jQueryPlugins/issues#issue/7)
            if ($.browser.mozilla && this.firstChild)
                this.firstChild.textContent = value;
            else
                this.innerHTML = value;
        });
        //http://dbj.org/dbj/?p=91
        var elementHtml = $('<div></div>').append($element.clone()).html();
        return elementHtml;
    }

    function _getBaseHref() {
        var port = (window.location.port) ? ':' + window.location.port : '';
        return window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + port + window.location.pathname;
    }

    function _getMarkup(element, opts) {
        var $element = $(element);
        var elementHtml = _getElementHTMLIncludingFormElements(element);

        var html = new Array();
        html.push('<html><head><title>' + opts["pageTitle"] + '</title>');
        if (opts["overrideElementCSS"]) {
            if (opts["overrideElementCSS"].length > 0) {
                for (var x = 0; x < opts["overrideElementCSS"].length; x++) {
                    var current = opts["overrideElementCSS"][x];
                    if (typeof (current) == 'string')
                        html.push('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="' + current + '" >');
                    else
                        html.push('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="' + current["href"] + '" media="' + current["media"] + '" >');
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $("link", document).filter(function () {
                return $(this).attr("rel").toLowerCase() == "stylesheet";
            }).each(function () {
                html.push('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="' + $(this).attr("href") + '" media="' + $(this).attr('media') + '" >');
            });
        }
        //Ensure that relative links work
        html.push('<base href="' + _getBaseHref() + '" />');
        html.push('</head><body style="' + opts["printBodyOptions"]["styleToAdd"] + '" class="' + opts["printBodyOptions"]["classNameToAdd"] + '">');
        html.push('<div class="' + $element.attr('class') + '">' + elementHtml + '</div>');
        html.push('<script type="text/javascript">function printPage(){focus();print();' + ((!$.browser.opera && !opts["leaveOpen"] && opts["printMode"].toLowerCase() == 'popup') ? 'close();' : '') + '}</script>');
        html.push('</body></html>');

        return html.join('');
    };
})(window);
```

Is there any way to identify the close event and end it peacefully OR do not show the [x] option at the right top corner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i struggled with this for the past 3 days, and came to the conclusion of the following:

these lines:

```
if (mainOptions["printMode"] == 'iframe') {
  if ($.browser.opera || (/chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())))
    mainOptions["printMode"] = 'popup';
}
```

are obsoletes and they seems to cause issues in Chrome, it happens that by the time when this plugin was created, Chrome and Opera have issues when printing an iframe content.

As of today that's not longer an issue (and since Opera uses Webkit as Chrome, i must assume this also happens to work on Opera as well).

So for now removes those lines and you will notice that the print dialog will not have the blank window anymore, hence you should not have this problem.